# How do disentangling and reordering of exponential operators work?

Tags: operators, group-theory, commutator, lie-algebra, wick-theorem

I have seen in several sources that by invoking Lie groups, $$e^{\alpha_1 g_1+\alpha_2 g_2 + \dots} = e^{\beta_1 g_1}e^{\beta_2 g_2}\dots $$ where $g_i$ are elements of a Lie algbera.

For example, take the two-mode squeeze operator in quantum optics:
$$e^{-\xi\hat{a}\hat{b}+\xi^*\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{b}^\dagger} = e^{-\frac{\xi^*}{|\xi|}\tanh|\xi|\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{b}^\dagger} e^{-\ln\cosh|\xi| \left(\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}+\hat{b}^\dagger\hat{b}+1\right)} e^{\frac{\xi}{|\xi|}\tanh|\xi| \hat{a}\hat{b}}.$$

A few other examples can be the displacement and the single-mode squeeze operators.

My question is what are the conditions under which we can disentangle the operators like this and also reorder them?

Comment: Naive question: do you know about the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) help?

Comment: @Philip Not so naive. The tricks in that bag are the first to try. "What are the conditions" is an absurdly expectant vision of cookbook codification of an art. The first background question to ask is:  do all bilinear close into a finite Lie algebra?  If so, can one easily work out such exponentials for its simplest faithful representation? Surely the OP has read up on these examples...

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos So the Lie algebra must be finite? If I have a finite Lie Algebra, next how to find the simplest representations?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Got it. As a different question, I had a 4-generator Lie Algebra with the issue that Lie algebra didn't look familiar at all, so I don't know which matrix representations should I be using. Is there a method that gives us the representations if we feed in all the commutators?

Comment: No, you identify the algebra from experience. There are not that many with 4 generators!  For your example, try to map the bilinears on your right to suitably normalized $\sigma_{\pm}, \sigma_z$.  Work out the algebra for your example in your question!

Comment: see DasGupta, A., 1996. Disentanglement formulas: An alternative derivation and some applications to squeezed coherent states. American Journal of Physics, 64(11), pp.1422-1427.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section III of this [classic](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107) illustrates the method. I'll bypass the subtle math and cut to the chase for your specific example, taking the trivial case of *ξ* real... you do general things to your satisfaction, yourself, or check the [ref](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.18183?casa_token=XkOYhW3Dp9kAAAAA:49Da9l08khiM3UX6wLYn-Eo5SOgUFtCm0mUDQR6TkDcbF1OGOc0RGUjADDXIBPZDe_KpMD_Uy7o) in the comment of @ZeroTheHero above.

This is an identity between exponentials of operators. In Lie group theory, composition of such exponentials (group elements) amounts to a single group element: an exponential of a linear combination of nested commutators of these operators ("the Lie algebra" of your l.h.s.). All commutators, even an infinity of them, ultimately close into a finite number of operators, a finite-dimensional Lie algebra. (There are also infinite-dimensional Lie algebras, but let's not go there...)

So what is the Lie algebra in your example? It's *su(1,1)*, but don't worry about it. I'll map it to the Pauli matrices, so you only need to recall *their* commutation relations, not even knowing names and such of the relevant Lie algebras; you only need to know these matrices are a faithful representation of the algebra: they reproduce all commutation relations of it exactly.

So,  define
$$
\sigma^+\equiv i a^\dagger b^\dagger, \qquad \sigma^-\equiv i a b, 
\qquad  \sigma_3\equiv 1+ a^\dagger a+ b^\dagger b, 
$$
and confirm that these obey this Lie algebra,
$$
[\sigma_3,\sigma^{\pm}]= \pm \sigma^{\pm}, \qquad [\sigma^+,\sigma^-]= \sigma_3. 
$$

- Now you know *Pauli matrices obey this Lie algebra as well*, so, if it held for them that
  $$
  e^{i\xi(\sigma^-- \sigma^+)}  = e^{i \tanh \xi ~\sigma^+ } e^{-\ln \cosh \xi ~ \sigma_3} e^{-i \tanh \xi ~\sigma^-} ,
  $$
  then the CBH combinatorics would be identical for your operators as well, and your identity would hold.

Indeed, the l.h.s is but
$$
e^{\xi \sigma_2}= \cosh \xi ~ 1\!\!1 +\sinh \xi ~ \sigma_2~. 
$$
The r.h.s., by dint of the two nilpotent exponents and the diagonal middle one, is
$$
(1\!\!1 + i \tanh \xi ~\sigma^+ ) ~~\operatorname{diag}(1/\cosh \xi , \cosh \xi) ~~(1\!\!1 - i \tanh \xi ~\sigma^- )\\ 
=\cosh \xi ~ 1\!\!1 -\sinh \xi ~ \sigma_2~,
$$
the complex conjugate of the above. Hmmmm...

I believe your stated identity has flakey signs on the left side, as seen by taking small *ξ*  and comparing the expanded exponentials!

In any case, you get the drift...

Check Prob 5 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_60FeHzTRnpclBnMThGc2hvcWM/view) to see the versatility of the method.